# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've been new to xCode and facing this issue while adding a new file to existing project. The error I receive is :

> duplicate symbol _main in:
>       /Users/jagtapawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pdf-gowwoupvsiukblehcdbaeublehki/Build/Intermediates/pdf.build/Debug/pdf.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
>       /Users/jagtapawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pdf-gowwoupvsiukblehcdbaeublehki/Build/Intermediates/pdf.build/Debug/pdf.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/func.o
>   ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

what I do is File -> New -> File. on the left panel select iOS source -> objective c -> next. It insists me to to enter

File: func

File type : Empty

Class : NSObject

my file hierarchy in Xcode is this way :

pdf

-func.m

--pdf

----main.m

--products

----pdf

whereas in finder the func.m and main.m are in the same folder pdf.
please help me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Do you have a `main()` function in both `func.m` and `main.m`?  You should only have one in `main.m`.

Comment: What does the code in func.m look like?

Comment: @EricGalluzzo ,Yeah , I've main() function in func.m and main.m. I wan't to run both files independently... just like it happens in java.How do I achieve it? Please help

Comment: @PhillipMills it consisted of simple swap program using a swap function and a main function which called the swap function.But when I faced issues in executing it, I just included simple "NSLog(@"Hi"); "... :P still it persists. Please help.

Comment: You can't have two `main` functions linked together in the same program.  To run two different "mains", you need two programs.

Comment: @PhillipMills I've two different programs with with main () of their own .i.e fun.m has a main() as well as main.m has main(). of which when I run it shows "Build failed"

Comment: An Objective-C file is not a program.  From what you've said, you **don't** have two different programs.  You're trying to link two different source files into one program.  Create two projects (or two targets), each with only one of those main() routines in it.

Comment: got it @PhillipMills. just one main() in one project.... thumbs up. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the same problem with the following code.

Add this to the Library Search Paths in Build Settings and make sure you select recursive, delete other library paths which might be absolute paths.

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)
```

May be it will help you.

**OR**

You have duplicate symbol method which means there are duplicate file in project

In your Target's Build Phase, under "Compile Sources" check if there are duplicate file and delete one if you have duplication.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I did as you instructed. I deleted the func.m and kept main.m which resulted  in just executing main.m. I need to execute func.m independently. Please help

Comment: Sorry I didn't say about the main function

Comment: there are no duplicate files in compile sources... just fun.m and main.m

Comment: Is it due to func.m and main.m has both individual main() and both lie under the same folder making it difficult to execute...?

Comment: @JagtaPawan Remove func.m from compile source and check weather it is giving error or not.

Comment: If my answer is helpful to tou mark it as answer.or give me up vote